# Python ImportError in compiling a file

Tags: python, compilation

I have a python script that I'm trying to compile to a .pyc file. The python script imports a variety of modules, including Tkinter, xlrd, and pandas. I'm using the line "python -m py_compile myfile.py" in the command prompt in the proper path. However, the pyc file gives an error of no module named xlrd when I try to run it. Help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I'm using Python 2.7 in Spyder

Edit2 relevant parts of my code:

```
import csv
import os
import time
import xlrd 
import random
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import pandas as pd
import shutil

    if namesfile.endswith('.csv'):
        df=pd.read_csv(namesfile)
    else:
        newformat='C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\%s\\your_temporary_csv.csv'%(bestfoldername)

        def csv_from_excel():

            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(namesfile)
            sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
            my_csv_file = open(newformat, 'wb')
            wr = csv.writer(my_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

            for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
                wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
            my_csv_file.close()


        csv_from_excel()

        df=pd.read_csv(newformat)
```

Comment: can we see your code?...:P

Comment: @Khalil its kind of long but I'll show parts of it I guess

Comment: What's the command you use to run the pyc file?

Comment: @ThinkChaos I used "python -m py_compile myfile.py"

Comment: @JeremyG Is that the only command you're executing? Once you have the pyc file, what do you do?

Comment: @ThinkChaos Yes that is the only command. I try opening the pyc file and it opens for about half a second, shows the error "No module named xlrd" then it closes

Comment: @JeremyG Then I think the error is just that the module can't be found. Are you sure it's properly installed? If you just run `python myfile.py` what happens?.

Comment: @ThinkChaos The same error occurs, which is strange because it works perfectly fine when run from the python script in Spyder

Comment: Spyder probably comes prepackaged with xlrd. You'll have to install it using `pip`.

Comment: @ThinkChaos I tried using "pip install xlrd" and "pip install pandas" but it gives the message "Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages"